# "На крайний случай": с запятой или без?

Tags: пунктуация

Нужна ли запятая: «На крайний случай, может быть использован такой способ»?

Answer (score 1):

Лучше, конечно, сказать " в крайнем случае". 
На мой взгляд, это выражение не является вводным, так как оно является членом предложения, точнее обстоятельством: может быть использован (когда?при каком условии?). Поэтому запятую ставить не нужно.